# Launch terminal with single keystroke

Tags: terminal

Back in my Quake playing days, You could always pull up the Quake console with the ` key, and it would scroll up from the bottom of the screen.

Even further back I remember the same behaviour with our school's BBC microcomputers, Acorn/Archimedes etc.

It strikes me that would be super-useful on OSX. I use the terminal all the time.

Can anyone think of a clean solution?

Comment: How is this different than launching any other app from a shortcut?  See the many previously asked/answered topics:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=launch+shortcut